# Hide "Add to Cart" button for logged in users in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

On my site (using Woocommerce 3.2.6), I want to hide "Add to Cart" button only for logged in users.

I have this code:

```
add_action('init', 'hide_price_add_cart_logged_in');
function hide_price_add_cart_logged_in() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {       
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
            'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
            'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Someone suggested me to use this:

```
add_action('init', 'hide_price_add_cart_logged_in');
function hide_price_add_cart_logged_in() { 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {       
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
            'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
            'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        return WooCommerce::instance();
    }
}
```

But that did **not** work...

I have inserted this code into functions.php file into my theme, but it don't seems to make any change. I still see add to cart button when check some product.

How to remove that button? Where is error in my function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_loop_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function remove_loop_add_to_cart_button() {
    // Only for logged in users
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function remove_add_to_cart_button() {
    // Only for logged in users
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    global $product;

    // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    }
    // For all other product types
    else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works

---

Instead of hiding add to cart button on archives pages (like shop) you could replace it with a button linked to the product. So the code will be instead:

```
// Replacing the button add to cart by a link to the product in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Only for logged in users
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';

    return $button;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function remove_add_to_cart_button() {
    // Only for logged in users
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    global $product;

    // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    }
    // For all other product types
    else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );;
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'shessvy_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );
 
function shessvy_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
 
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
 
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'shessvy_print_login_to_see', 31 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shessvy_print_login_to_see', 11 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'shessvy_print_login_to_see', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

    }
}
 
function shessvy_print_login_to_see() {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '" rel="nofollow ugc">' . __('Login to add this item to your cart', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```